# Retrieving MySql connection information using Kudu on Azure Web Sites

Tags: node.js, azure, connection-string, azure-web-app-service, kudu

Is there a way with Kudu (or some other means) to retrieve the MySql connection information when I push with Git?

I know I can access it through the portal, but I want to write a build script that generates some files based on the Azure Web Site I'm going to push to. I also am aware of the App Settings, but I don't want duplication there.

I'm deploying a custom built WordPress instance where I want to build the `wp-config.php` file dynamically and not have it checked in to my repository.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, your connection string is available as an environment setting.
To experiment with custom scripts use kuduexec (http://blog.amitapple.com/post/45675601255/azurewebsiteterminal)

Comment: the connection string is available to you as an environment setting it should be named ```MYSQLCONNSTR_{name}```, using the simple terminal to your site you can experiment with how to use it in a custom script.